# how to update User-Defined Properties in core.properties on solr collections

Tags: curl, solr, solrcloud

we are using solr cloud 7.7.2 and all works fine with our collections. Below is the kind of simplified curl statement we use to create our collections:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{"create": {"name": "organization-3.0.0", "config": "organization-3.0.0-cfg", "numShards": "1", "replicationFactor": "3", "maxShardsPerNode": "1", 
  "properties": {
    "solr": { 
      "db": {
        "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
      }
    } 
  }
}}' http://192.168.0.10:8983/api/collections
```

it is inspired form https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/configuring-solrconfig-xml.html#user-defined-properties-in-core-properties

As you can see we have a json as value for the "properties" attribute. by doing so, the properties end up being added to the core.properties (in each shards) and we use these properties to perform data import via DIH.

When we want to update the value of the "properties" attribute, we actually create a new collection under a new name ex: organization-3.0.1 and reimport all data via DIH (which can take a lot of time).

We would like to be able to really update the value of the "properties" attribute on existing collections.

I could not see the “properties” attribute being a valid attribute in the documentation https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/collections-api.html#modifycollection

So I wonder if there are any ways to modify the "properties" attribute on solr collections?

Answer (score 0):

There is - the problem for you is that it was introduced with Solr 7.3 - the version after the one you have active. I suggest upgrading to a more recent version - go all the way to 8.5.x (it should be an easier upgrade since it's only one major version between them).

> [COLLECTIONPROP](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/collections-api.html#collectionprop)
>
> Add, edit or delete a collection property.
>
> `/admin/collections?action=COLLECTIONPROP&name=collectionName&propertyName=propertyName&propertyValue=propertyValue`

Comment: thx @matslindh, sorry I made a huge typo, we are using 7.7.2. I tried to run `curl "http://192.168.0.10:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=COLLECTIONPROP&name=organization-3.0.0&propertyName=testprop&propertyValue=testvalue01&wt=xml"` and was expecting to see the prop added to the `core.properties` next to `solr.db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` Any idea what I am mistaking or misunderstanding, please?

Comment: What's the response to the call to `COLLECTIONPROP`? How are you looking up the property values?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">1</int>
</lst>
</response>`
and I was expecting the property to be inserted in the generated core.properties located in `solr/organization-3.0.0_shard1_replica_n2`

Comment: I'm not sure if it'll be visible there or just stored inside Zookeeper as a configuration overlay.